# How to loop through a variables in Magento Email Template?

Tags: email, templates, loops, magento, iteration

Let's say I've the following variables to pass to my Email Template:

```
$vars = array(
    'products'  => $products,
);
```

Where `$products` is a collection, how could I iterate over this collection in Email template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe that Magento's templating engine is clever enough to do loops. Instead, use an inline block, as Magento does for order items. Something like this:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='path/to/your/template.phtml' products=$products}}
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: thank a lot, I finally did something like that, that's awesome that we are not able to do such things..

Comment: I have same doubt, I did added above block in my email template. But Nothing is working. If you want I can post the code

Comment: Any idea what am doing wrong here ?: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/360406/magento-2-3-5-order-email-observer-custom-block-enable-to-pass-array

Answer (score 1):

The above works, but an alternative would be to let your XML do the work by calling the layout handle in the email template:

```
{{layout handle="email_stuff"}}
```

In your local.xml or module.xml or where ever you like:

```
<email_stuff>
    <block type="yourblock/type" name="email_stuff" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
</email_stuff>
```

I guess the main difference is where you're doing most of your email "work". I've used this method for loading in email headers/footers that stay the same in each template. The previous answer is likely simpler for basic tasks, however.